# Detecting security alerts in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

For example, when accessing a site using HTTPS, IE will sometimes popup a security warning. These are not JavaScript popups.

How can I detect these popups using JavaScript?

Comment: You're cooking something nasty

Comment: You can't, luckily. Do you want to visit a phishing site with faked certificate which blocks the browsers security warning?

Comment: I don't mean block the security warning, just detect if they popup. Thanks. May be I shall find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are there for a reason. As far as *how* to notify the user that a secure page contains non-secure resources Microsoft's decision to use an "alert box" may be questionable, but trying to meddle with the warnings themselves is not the way to go. Instead, look over your site and make sure your user's browsers are fetching content and resources correctly (securely) in the first place, as they should.